# How to send messages in every server only to channels that allows it to (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that sends messages in every server to channels that allows it to send messages.

Here's the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready(): #executes when ran
    print("Ready!")
    while 1 == 1: #loops code below
        for i in client.guilds: #going to all servers
            for j in i.channels: #going to all channel in server
               if isinstance(j, discord.TextChannel): #if is text channel then send message
                  await j.send('message')
```

Error:

```
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the channels to make sure they are truly text channels, you have to make sure you have the permissions to actually send messages:

```
if (j.permissions_for(i.me).send_messages):
    await j.send("message")
```

You can read about channel permissions [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.permissions_for). However, I question *why* you want to do this, as this seems somewhat malicious. Also, you will hit a rate limit like this, and I personally do not want to be responsible for telling someone the best way to get around that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked, I wanted to do this for sending messages to servers with my bot about updates, etc. It's nothing malicious.